# Linq Sqlfunctions

Tags: linq

I would link to convert Datetime  columns as string.
this should be happen in Database exaple if we use System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions
that will be append the same to the query and executed in Database.

In all the posts suggested, First need to queried then we need to select. In select we can use .ToString(). Rather than getting the records first i would like to convert at the time of fetch.

My requirement. I have enity Employee.

```
public class EmpEntities
{
 public string Id { get; set; }
 public DateTime CreatedDate { get; set; }
}
```

Assume my data 
Emp-19,2012-01-01 11:33:454
Emp-17,1999:06:06 12:44:898

My search criteria is 20 , In all fields any employee is having 20 (contains)
This i need to filter list of properties contains need to be checked. to do that i need to convert my created date column as string in linq.

```
var query=
(from ee in entities.Employee
 where ee.CreatedDate.Value.ToString().Contains("20")
select ee).ToList();
```

if we use the above one it will throug error.

if we use the below one works fine.

```
var query=
     (from emp in entities.Employee                        
       select emp)
.AsEnumerable()
.Where(x=>x.CreatedDate.Value.ToString().Contains("20"));
```

I need to check contains for Date time property for entity. Is there any way to convert the datetime property to string and check for contains in linq.

i need to convert my datetime property to string then i need to use contains.

So here my problem is i want to filter the data at database level
for example like this
i am preparing for the  employee id

```
var query= (from emp in entities.Employee.Where(x =>   System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions.StringConvert((decimal?)x.Empid).Contains("20"))                   
                select emp).ToList();
```

this equivalent in sql query is.

```
SELECT  1 AS [C1],  [Extent1].[name] AS [name] FROM [dbo].[Employee] AS [Extent1]
WHERE STR( CAST( [Extent1].[EmpId] AS decimal(19,0))) LIKE N'%5%'
```

In sql execution it is converted integer type to string and executed the condition while fetching the record.

Similarly i would like to filter created date along with empid. But i am not able convert the datetime column to string so that i can use contains.

Is there any way to achieve the above one what i did for integer datatype.

Comment: I dont see how the title or tag matches the question? Its also not descriptive, and looks like you want to tell something, not ask it.

Comment: Code is updated please check once.

Comment: In your whole question, the only thing I can see you asking is to convert `DateTime` to a `string` so you can see if it contains anything. In which `string date = DateTime.ToString()` would help. then `if (date.contains......)`.

Answer (score 1):

There is a short answer to this: no. But I think that sgmoore is right in pointing out the pitfalls in your method. A string representation of a `DateTime` can contain a string anywhere, so how useful is that?

It looks like you just want to select dates `>= 2000-01-01` which can be done by

```
var d1 = new DateTime(2000,1,1);
var query = from emp in entities.Employee
            where emp.CreatedDate >= d1
            select emp;
```

Please tell me if this does not meet your intentions and why a match `LIKE %20%` would matter so much. If it does, only the approach with `.AsEnumerable()` will do the job.

Answer (score 0):

With Linq2Sql you can do something like :

```
var query=
   (from ee in entities.Employee
    where SqlMethods.Like(ee.CreatedDate.Value.ToString() , "%20%")
    select ee).ToList();
```

Got to ask, why?  I am struggling to think of any possible reason why anyone would want something like this?

I presume your know this will match dates like

```
1900-01-01 20:00:00 
1900-01-01 00:00:20
1900-01-20 00:00:00
1920-01-01 00:00:00
2000-01-01 00:00:00
```

etc, etc

Comment: In below link INQ to Entities obviously supports System.Data.Objects.SqlClient.SqlFunctions, but not System.Data.Linq.SqlClient.SqlMethods.Like. http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/lightswitch/thread/5ede2db0-a4f9-4178-84c0-fabf4d3a57fa